# How to preload some part of google maps?

Tags: javascript, performance, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, preload

I'm building a web app with Google Maps API, I need to zoom into an area smoothly, so I use `setTimeout` to increase the zoom level every second, but in some place with bad network, the map images are loaded too slow that the page quickly turn to a white page....

so my question is is it possible to preload some part of Google Maps(zoom from 3 to 16 of a point)

Comment: I am having the same issue. Want to make the change of zoom level smoother...

Comment: @Flaudre have you tried RASG's solution?

Comment: Perhaps zooming in slowly isn't the best user experience for users on slow connections? Even if you pre-load all the data they will have to wait for a lot of images to load at some point

Comment: @Flaudre check the answer please.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you could probably pre-load it in a hidden div or iframe.

but you should make sure it is not against the [Google Maps/Google Earth APIs Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms)

> 10.1.3 Restrictions against Data Export or Copying.
>
> (b) No Pre-Fetching, Caching, or Storage of Content. You must not pre-fetch,
> cache, or store any Content, except that you may store: (i) limited
> amounts of Content for the purpose of improving the performance of
> your Maps API Implementation if you do so temporarily, securely, and
> in a manner that does not permit use of the Content outside of the
> Service; and (ii) any content identifier or key that the Maps APIs
> Documentation specifically permits you to store. For example, you must
> not use the Content to create an independent database of “places.”

Comment: Reading that it looks like it's ok to preload it to improve performance.

Comment: It seems ToS is not against @RASG 's offered solution. So go with it & don't worry! Dude, We back you in any court !

Answer (score 7):

**Make some code**

I've just created a script based on the 5-years-old idea by RASG. Let's create a hidden map and when it is fully loaded, zoom it in. We do it again and again until it caches all the zooms. The working [fiddle is here](https://jsfiddle.net/ishukshin/ke5gmpjy/). I've placed an info `div` in the top right corner to view how zoom progress.

```
// init the hidden map
var mapOptions = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(center.lat, center.lng),
  zoom: minZoom + 1
};
var preMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas-hidden'), mapOptions);

// when the current hidden map is fully loaded, zoom it in 
preMap.addListener('tilesloaded', function() {
  $('#out').html('Zoom ' + preMap.getZoom() + ' preloaded');

  // if there is zoom to zoom-in, do it after some rest
  if(preMap.getZoom() < maxZoom) {
    setTimeout(function(){
      preMap.setZoom(preMap.getZoom() + 1);
    }, 50);
  }
});
```

**Does it really cache the map?**

Well, clear browser cache and open the fiddle.

[image]

In browser network activity we can see a lot of images downloading. Then zoom the map in and watch the activity again. Looks like all the images are loaded from cache.

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: You can calculate the speed of your slow zoom-in by the time the first two caches get.

Comment: very nice! +1 for getting your hands dirty :)

Comment: Hey ivan, thanks a lot for the effort. I checked the page too late to reward some bounty. I hope you are okay with a mere upvote.